# How to merge sqlite3 session extension sessions?

Tags: sql, c, sqlite

I'm using the c API of the [sqlite3 session extension](https://www.sqlite.org/sessionintro.html) and wondering if the session extension can be used to merge sqlite3 sessions that already have been written to file.

Following the tutorial referenced above I was able to register sqlite3 sessions by writing them to file one by one, e.g. for an UPDATE call I end up with a session file, and with another INSERT call I get another file, and so on. These transactions are triggered by UI button callbacks. I wonder if the session files could be somehow merged afterwards into one single session file, so that calling [sqlite3changeset_apply()](https://www.sqlite.org/session/sqlite3changeset_apply.html) with this merged session file as its parameter I could end up with the same result as if I called sqlite3changeset_apply() on a list of session files. The reason I would like to do this is that I'd like to transfer only one session file instead of a folder of session files.

I tried iterating over a session list calling subsequent sqlite3changeset_apply() on a copy of the original database while registering the session, but in that I case I eventually get a session file with zero size (although the copy database would contain all the expected changes).
I could not find anything on this in the official documentation nor on the web.

Answer (score 1):

‍♀️‍♂️ necromancy alert ‍♂️‍♀️

You're probably looking for the [`sqlite3changeset_concat`](https://www.sqlite.org/session.html#sqlite3changeset_concat) function:

> This function is used to concatenate two changesets, A and B, into a single changeset. The result is a changeset equivalent to applying changeset A followed by changeset B.

There is also a streaming version, `sqlite3changeset_concat_strm`.

If you need to combine many changesets, you can use the type [`sqlite3_changegroup`](https://www.sqlite.org/session/changegroup.html) and its associated functions.